# Optimising z3 input

Tags: z3

I am trying to optimize z3 python input that is generated from my models. I am able to run it on models up 15k constraints (200 states) and then z3 stops finishing in reasonable time (<10 minutes). Is there a way to optimize the constraints that are generated from my models ?

Model for 3 states:

http://pastebin.com/EHZ1P20C

Comment: The model you posted looks fine. If you include links to models that take more than 1min to solve, we may be able to improve the performance by using a custom strategy.

Comment: What is a "custom strategy" ?

Comment: It is explained in these links: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/strategies, http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the link below you can find model that takes ~30s to be solved. I also have model that takes ~70 minutes but I suppose its too big to be considered. http://pastebin.com/F5iuhN42

Answer (score 2):

The performance of the script http://pastebin.com/F5iuhN42 can be improved by using a custom strategy. Z3 allows users to define custom strategies/solvers. [This tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/strategies) shows how to define strategies/tactics using the Z3 Python API. In the script http://pastebin.com/F5iuhN42, if we replace the line

```
s = Solver()
```

with

```
s = Then('simplify', 'elim-term-ite', 'solve-eqs', 'smt').solver()
```

the runtime will decrease from 30 secs to 1 sec (on my machine).

The procedure `Then` is creating a strategy/tactic composed of 4 steps:

- Simplifier (i.e., a rewriter that applies rules such as `x + 1 - x + y` ==> `1 + y`
- Elimination of expressions of the form `If(a, b, c)` where `b` and `c` are not Boolean. The script makes extensive use this kind of expression. The tactic `elim-term-ite` will apply transformations that eliminate this kind of expression.
- Equational solver. It applies transformations such as `x = a And F[x]` ==> `F[a]`. In the script above, this tactic can eliminate more than 1000 variables.
- The tactic `smt` invokes a general purpose SMT solver in Z3.

The method `.solver()` converts a Z3 tactic/strategy into a solver object that provides the `add` and `check` methods. The tutorial that I included in the beginning of the message has more details.

Comment: In the example that I have sent it works like a charm. Though in other examples (with the same generation method) I am not seeing any difference. Can you tell me how did you learned that Z3 eliminated 1000 variables with solve-eqs. Maybe I could use that measure to learn why other scripts do not experience the same improvements.

Comment: In the beginning of the file, you should include `set_option(verbose=10)`. Then, Z3 will display a bunch of messages, including one saying the number of eliminated variables during preprocessing.

Comment: Can you also explain meaning of these output: (simplifier :num-exprs 5258 :num-asts 7694 :time 0.00 :before-memory 1.37 :after-memory 1.50), I suppose "num-exprs" is self explanatory.

Comment: These are the statistics produced by the Z3 simplifier: `num-exprs` is the number of objects used to encode your problem after the simplifier is applied; `num-asts` is the total number of objects used to encode expressions, declarations and sorts/types in Z3; `before-memory` (`after-memory`) is the memory consumption before and after applying the simplifier; and `time` is the approx amount of time spent on the simplifier.